# Laravel 8 - could not find driver on namecheap shared hosting

Tags: laravel-8, shared-hosting, namecheap

I've been trying to host a project to a shared hosting on namecheap, getting the same error:

could not find driver (SQL: select * from `slider` order by `view_id` asc)

PDO_MYSQL is enabled in the server as I have checked from phpinfo()

please help :(

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

I'm currently having the same issue on hostnownow. I googled the issue and found out that I have to enable some php extensions of which I did, only for me to be getting access denied **could not find driver (SQL: select * from `users`**

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).